# X-axis scaling with D3 JavaScript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scaling

Here is my working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aj3g5tqg/5/).

I have two problems here:

1. I don't know how to scale x-axis so that it only shows 2011-2012-2013 etc. (Currently it displays 2011-2011.5-2012).
2. When I have a long list of `datajson`, chart doesn't fit to the current window. Therefore, I can't see all of the researcher names in that case.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First part**

You can use the `.ticks`function to specify number of values in your axis :

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("top")
        .ticks(end_year-start_year);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aj3g5tqg/7/)

**Second part**

You can make a dynamic height for your graph like this :

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 200, bottom: 0, left: 20},
        width = 300,
        height = datajson.length * 20 + margin.top + margin.bottom;
```

Maybe, you just have to adapt the item height value

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aj3g5tqg/10/)